# I put frozen veg back in the fridge instead of freezer

Tags: vegetables

I put frozen veg back in the fridge instead of freezer.  This morning I put them back in freezer.  Will they be ok to eat when I cook them.

Answer (score 1):

Safe, most likely.

Will they be worse ? yes, freezing and thawing break down cell structure.

You will loose a lot of the vegetable structure and texture, they will be more mushy.